# GitPython: remove multiple tags locally and remote

Tags: python, git, git-tag, gitpython

I'm using GitPython to remove multiple tags. I'm doing it with this code:

```
def delete_tags(self, tags):
    remote = self.__repo.remote(name='origin')

     for tag in tags:
        self.__repo.git.tag('-d', tag)  # remove locally
        remote.push(refspec=(':%s' % (tag)))  # remove from remote
```

I have a performance issue with this code. The command

```
remote.push(refspec=(':%s' % (tag)))
```

is working very slow. It takes a few seconds to delete each tag in the remote. I have 200+ tags, which consuming a lot of time for me.

Is this possible to delete all selected tags (`tags`) with ONE push?

Comment: Servers that accept `git push` accept multiple refspecs in one push. How, or even if, you can specify that in GitPython, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

As torek commented, git itself allows for multiple refspecs in a push command.

Then GitPython 3.0 API reference explicitly mentions the multiple refspecs possibility ([here](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.Remote.push))

*(from "Fetch" section which is referenced by the "Push" section itself for that parameter)*

> Fetch supports multiple refspecs (as the underlying git-fetch does) - supplying a list rather than a string for ‘refspec’ will make use of this facility.

Comment: `remote.push(refspec=[':%s' % tag for tag in tags])`

Comment: @phd Thanks for the specific syntax, I was unsure.